# Find the holomorphic function $f(z)=u(r,\theta)+iv(r,\theta)$ the more general for which $v(r,\theta)=0$

Tags: complex-analysis

Find the holomorphic function $f(z)=u(r,\theta)+iv(r,\theta)$ the more general for which $v(r,\theta)=0$.

According to the Cauchy-Riemann equations, I got $\frac{\partial v}{\partial r}=0$
and $\frac{\partial v}{\partial \theta}=1$.

So as we have $u_{\theta}=0 \implies u=h(r)$. Furthermore, $u_r=h_r(r)=1 \implies h(r)=r+c$. Hence, the final answer is $f(z)=r+c+i \theta.$

Am I right? Otherwise, how could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The idea using Cauchy-Riemann is fine (an alternative would be the open mapping theorem for holomorphic functions if you heard about it). However, the result is not quite correct. If $v$ is constant, what will you get for the derivative? Not 1, but...? Proceeding from there with the right value will give you the right answer.